# TeamCity finish build trigger not firing

Tags: triggers, teamcity

I have a TeamCity job which builds our website from a given branch. I am trying to get a build which runs a couple of automated Selenium tests against that site that was just built.

The build configuration I want to kick off another build configuration when it finishes is called "**Site Alpha – Feature Branch QA Builds**", but it doesn't seem to fire any finish build triggers, so I went back to basics.

I tried setting up 2 new jobs for testing, "**test trigger build > run**" and "**test triggered build >plain_run > plain**". Both do simple command line "echo" statements and the second one has a finish build trigger configured to fire when the first one finishes. This works perfectly.

I added another finish build trigger to "**test triggered build >plain_run > plain**" to build when "**Site Alpha – Feature Branch QA Builds**" finishes. When I build "**Site Alpha – Feature Branch QA Builds**" the finish build trigger on "**test triggered build >plain_run > plain**" does not fire.

All 3 build configurations are compatible with all of the build agents.

I am using **TeamCity Enterprise 8.0.1 (build 27435)** and accessing it in Firefox 31.0

(1) "Build Triggers" configuration page for "**test triggered build >plain_run > plain**"
[image: Test Triggered Build Build Triggers]

(2) Build log for "**test trigger build > run**" (#6 here triggered #1 in image (3), #7 here triggered #3 in image (3) )
[image: test trigger build log]

(3) build log for "**test triggered build >plain_run > plain**" (#2 triggered manually, #1 and #3 triggered by above, image (2) )
[image: test triggered build log]

(4) build log for "**Site Alpha – Feature Branch QA Builds**" (being built regularly, but hasn't fired trigger once)
[image: Feature Branch QA Builds log]

Comment: Why you arent just using two build steps?

Comment: I'd like to be able to run the second one without running the first. Had it worked straight off it would have been great, at this rate I may have to resort to adding an extra step to the first build configuration. I also was trying to work out how to make the automated selenium tests run in TeamCity, I hadn't done it before, and didn't want to break the branch site build whilst I was investigating.

Answer (score 0):

When you say the dependent build does not fire, does it actually show up as queued or does it give any error message

- If it shows up as queued, it will normally have a message to explain why it is not running
- If it throws an error instead of getting into a queue , you can debug the error
- If it is none of the above , try forcing a manual run and see if that throws any error or is succeeding. In case it is succedding can you please attach a snapshot of your issue
- You can also edit the build configuration, you can see the build agents where this target can run on. If there are no build agents, you need to figure out why it can not run on any build agent

Comment: I've added screenshots and it appears the build is not being queued. There are no errors in builds which have been run on the "test triggered build" build configuration